# Got integer result when printed return numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not quite understood why I got `@res = 1` when print `return 0.57`? I need to return the numeric results in my UDF function.

```
DECLARE @text1 VARCHAR(255) = 'some text'
DECLARE @text2 VARCHAR(255) = 'same another text'
DECLARE @res AS NUMERIC
DECLARE @i INT = 0
DECLARE @exist_counter INT = 0

WHILE @i < (LEN(@text1) - 2)
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1

    IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@text1, @i, 3), @text2) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @exist_counter = @exist_counter + 1
            --print @exist_counter
            --print SUBSTRING(@text1,@i,3)
    END
END

PRINT @i
PRINT @exist_counter
PRINT cast(@exist_counter AS NUMERIC) / cast(nullif(@i, 0) AS NUMERIC)

SET @res = cast(@exist_counter AS NUMERIC) / cast(nullif(@i, 0) AS NUMERIC)

PRINT @res
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Why are you using a `WHILE` when you're using a query language, not a programming language? You also don't declare a scale/precision for your `numeric` data types; you really should as otherwise you will get unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) post

> Numeric data types that have fixed precision and scale

So you should change **scale** like.

```
declare @res as numeric(18, 2)
```

**Why?**

As @HABO's comment, "The default precision is **18.**" and "The default **scale is 0**" where scale is "*The number of decimal digits that are stored to the right of the decimal point.*"

Comment: More specifcally, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) states: "The default precision is 18." and "The default scale is 0" where _scale_ is "The number of decimal digits that are stored to the right of the decimal point." The OP needs to change the _scale_, not _precision_, to get decimal places in the result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @HABO